# How to import Syncfusion Theme studio custom CSS file in angular

Tags: css, angular, ej2-syncfusion

How to include the custom scss files we download from Syncfusion Theme Studio into angular cli?

The site recommends adding the URL to the styles section in `angular.json`. Is there a way to avoid doing that and import it into `styles.scss`.
I have tried by adding:

```
@import './scss/themestudio/multiselect-bootstrap4-202104281445211345-8b09079-/bootstrap4.scss';
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just copy/paste the new css or scss content directly into your existing styles.scss file

Comment: i did but the changes doesnt apply

Comment: copy the actual css styles not the `import` statement

Answer (score 0):

We have created sample for your reference that you can get from the following link.

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ej2-sync-343293087

We request you to just include the downloaded SCSS file from Theme Studio and copy the file into the application repo. Also, need to modify our “angular.json” as in following code snippet.

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/style/material.scss"
            ],
```

Please get back to us if you have any queries.